# Camera taken Images display in landscape mode in imageview?

Tags: android, bitmap, orientation, landscape

I am currently working on an image processing Application. When i select Camera taken images it displays as landscape mode only, other Images display properly in imageview. How can i rectify this....(Note: I am not using camera,just captured images).

Comment: you can examine the EXIF data and see if the corresponding exif-tag is set to landscape.